# Merging select elements from multiple XML files

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to take the same element from 225 different files with the exact same formatting and combine it into one file using XSL. Each file looks like this:

```
<thickness_metafile>
  <job_bundle>
        <analysis_description>
             <material_table>
                material
              </material_table>
              <thickness_set>
                 ray element 1
                 ray element 2
                 ray element 3 
              </thickness_set>
        </analysis_description>
 </job_bundle>
```

Because everything from each file is identical except for the  section, I'd like to copy each thickness_set from the last 224 files and paste them in to the first file directly under the first thickness_set. Essentially, I'd like the output to look like this:

```
<thickness_metafile>
  <job_bundle>
        <analysis_description>
             <material_table>
                material
              </material_table>
              <thickness_set>
                 ray element 1
                 ray element 2
                 ray element 3 
              </thickness_set>
              <thickness_set>
                 ray element 4
                 ray element 5
                 ray element 6 
              </thickness_set>
              <thickness_set>
                 ray element 7
                 ray element 8
                 ray element 9 
              </thickness_set>
        </analysis_description>
 </job_bundle>
```

There should be 225 thickness sets in the final edited file. I've tried a few things with some success but the output is not formatted the way I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have xml files with names "file1.xml", "file2.xml", "file3.xml" and so on. We can process them in xsl using a recursive template call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="thickness_set">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:call-template name="file-loop">
            <!-- continue with file number 2 -->
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="2"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="file-loop">
        <xsl:param name="count"/>

        <!-- no more than 226 files -->
        <xsl:if test="$count &lt; 226">
            <thickness_set>
                <xsl:variable name="fi" select="document(concat('file',$count,'.xml'))"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$fi//thickness_set"/>
            </thickness_set>
            <xsl:call-template name="file-loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count+1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The first xml file (with any name) we pass in the xsl. Others, with names "file2.xml" and so on, are automatically loaded.